# PHPUnit - "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction" error when running tests in bulk

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

Consider quite big monolythic dokerized application based on Laravel 5.1. When trying to run some tests in bulk we sometimes get following error:

`Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`

The strange thing is that when I restart the exact test that failed it runs smoothly.

My observations:

- The error only occurs while running tests in bulk, i.e. by calling `./vendor/bin/phpunit` or in IDE. When I run single test or single test class everything works ok.
- The tests are generally slow for this application. Running ca. 700 tests can last up to 30 minutes.
- There is no particullar type of tests that fails. There is no general rule to pinpoint what kind of tests cause this problem.

Stack:

- Laravel 5.1
- Docker
- Mysql
- PHP 7.0
- PHPUnit 5.7

Comment: Missing a `parent::tearDown();` somewhere? Uncommitted transaction issue? Check `QueryException` trace and sql log - if last attempted query was on `some_table`, perhaps `some_table` was locked by a previous test.